# Sind die Wörter bereitstellen, sicherstellen und gewährleisten gleichwertig?

Tags: vocabulary, synonym

Die Worte

- bereitstellen
- sicherstellen
- gewährleisten

Sind sie gleichwertig oder unterscheiden sie sich? Falls ja, wie?

**EDIT: Ich habe die Schritte nachgebildet, die mich dazu veranlassen, die Frage zu stellen**

Die drei haben widerspruchsvolle Übersetzungen in meine Muttersprache sowie auf Englisch. Z. B. pons übersetzt **bereitstellen** wie *liefern*, aber Lingea sagt, dass es *garantieren* (= *sagen, dass es so sein würde*) bedeutet. Laut Glosbe.com auf Englisch, es ist auch *liefern*, aber polnische übersetzungen sind der Bedeutung von *vorbereiten*, *ernennen* oder *bestimmen* näher. Kann mann nür eine Dientsleistung *bereistellen/liefern*, oder auch konkrete Objekte? Auf polnisch Pons behauptet aber, dass „bereitstellen“ = *zur Verfügung stellen*, und nicht *liefern*.

Mit **sicherstellen** bin ich nicht sicher, ob es nur *wörtlich versichern* bedeutet, oder auch *alles tun, um es möglich zu machen*. Linguee.com nennt diese Beispiele: *Einhaltung sicherstellen*, *Konformität sicherstellen*, und *Erfüllung sicherstellen*. Jedoch gibt Pons *garantieren* für das einige Synonym, während Glosbe *versprechen* wie Übersetzung liefert – alle beide hinweisen, dass es nür wörtlich ist.

Woxikon behauptet, dass **gewährleisten** *zusagen*, *versprechen* oder *garrantieren* bedeutet. Aber Linguee.com sagt, dass man kann sagen: *Einhaltung gewährleisten*, *Konformität gewährleisten*, *die Preisstabilität gewährleisten*, *Erfüllung gewährleisten* – wie **bereistellen**, aber es ist nie wie das Synonyme gennant.

Wenn man alle drei vergleicht, z. B. Dict.cc benutzend, gibt es immer dieselbe Übersetzungen für sicherstellen und **gewährleisten**, aber ganz **unterschiedliche** (auch anders als andere Quellen) für **bereitstellen**:

[**bereitstellen:**](https://www.dict.cc/?s=bereitstellen)

- to provide
- to supply
- to allocate
- to hold sth available

[**sicherstellen:**](https://www.dict.cc/?s=sicherstellen)

- to ensure ✓
- to warrant ✓
- to safeguard ✓
- to guarantee ✓
- to insure ✓

[**gewährleisten:**](https://www.dict.cc/?s=gew%C3%A4hrleisten)

- to ensure ✓
- to warrant ✓
- to safeguard ✓
- to guarantee ✓
- to insure ✓

Nach Ansicht einiger Personen sind diese offensichtlich und eindeutig verschieden, aber der Unterschied entgeht mir.

Comment: Schon google translate gibt für alle Wörter unterschiedliche Übersetzungen.... welches Wörterbuch verwendest Du?

Comment: Glosbe.com, reverso.net, linguee.com und pons.de. Google Translate is aber keine gute Quelle...

Comment: Ja, google ist meist miserabel, aber alleine die Tatsache, dass Google verschiedene Ergebnisse bringt, beantwortet die Frage: NEIN, die Worte sind nicht gleichwertig, auch wenn sie gewisse Bedeutungsüberschneidungen haben. Auch bei linguee werden alle drei unterschiedlich übersetzt...

Comment: @torsten link warum diese Webseite haben, wenn die Leute immer sagen, andere Seite zu benutzen? Ich habe 60 Beispiele gesehen, und ich habe keine Unterschied gesehen auf Linguee und Reverso. Es gibt die Antwort für jede frage irgendwie, sondern ich habe die Frage hier angestellt. Spanische, Chinesische, Russische, Franzözische und Englische SE Gemainschaften können beantworten anstatt bemerken, dass es Bücher und Internet gibt. So viel ist klar.

Comment: This site is about the usage and rules of the German language. It is not well-suited to replace a dictionary, thesaurus, or conjugation table. If you have already consulted such sources and still have questions, please edit your question to explain what you found and why it did not help. See this post on Meta for more information.

Comment: Allein das Google Translate verschiedene Ergebnisse bringt, beantwortet die Frage. **Nein**, tut es nicht. Wie schon selbst festgestellt, ist Google meist miserabel und vor allem gibt es nur 1 Wort als mögliche Übersetzung zurück, was überhaupt nicht aufschlussreich sein muss. Genauso gut könnte Google sowohl Kopf, als auch Birne und Haupt mit "head" übersetzen, was noch lange nicht bedeutet, dass die 3 Begriffe äquivalent sind. Ebenso verhält es sich hier.

Comment: Ich empfehle http://dict.cc. Dort werden viele Übersetzungmöglichkeiten genannt. Dabei sieht man die Überschneidungen der Begriffe, aber auch die Unterschiede.

Comment: @MrVocabulary: Verstehe ich es richtig, dass die eigene Recherche gleiche Übersetzungen liefert, dennoch die Frage offen bleibt, ob bzw. inwiefern diese Worte sich in der Bedeutung unterscheiden?

Comment: Schreibe bitte etwas ausführlicher, welche Übersetzungen du wo gefunden hast und was genau das Problem ist. Den Hinweis auf google.translate finde ich ziemlich daneben. Aber auch dict.cc liefert verschiedene Übersetzungen für die genannten Wörter. Hier gibt es viele Leute, die gern bereit sind, dir zu helfen, wenn deine Frage erkennen lässt, dass du dir selbst Mühe gegeben hast, eine Lösung zu finden, dann aber irgendwo stecken geblieben bist. ;)

Comment: @TorstenLink Ich habe eine zusätzliche Erklärung geliefert, bitte öffnen Sie sie erneut.

Comment: @MrVocabulary, danke fürs Editieren. Ich votiere für die Wiedereröffnung.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich ich bin sehr verbunden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Während auf einer abstrakten Ebene es darum geht, dass etwas sicher da ist, wo es (noch) nicht ist, unterscheiden sich drei Worte im Gebrauch dennoch:

**bereitstellen**

- engl. Übersetzung nach [leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/bereitstellen) z.B. to provide sth / to supply / to make sth. available
- [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bereitstellen): etwas (für jemanden) zur Verfügung stellen

Für etwas, das noch fehlt wo es erwartet wird, sorgen, dass es (zur richtigen Zeit) da ist.

**sicherstellen**

- engl. Übersetzung nach [leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/sicherstellen) z.B. to ensure / to guarantee / to make sure
- [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/sicherstellen):

  - etwas vor einer Gefahr/ einem Zugriff sichern
  - etwas (durch besondere Maßnahmen) gewährleisten
  - etwas zweifelsfrei feststellen

Dafür sorgen, dass etwas so ist wie es sein soll. Ähnlichkeit mit *gewährleisten*.

**gewährleisten**

- engl Übersetzung nach [leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/gew%C3%A4hrleisten) z.B. to ensure / to guarantee / to warrant sth.)
- [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/gew%C3%A4hrleisten): etwas garantieren, sichern

Garantieren & durchsetzen, dass etwas ist wie es sein soll/ war. Ähnlichkeit mit *sicherstellen*.

Bei den englischen Übersetzungsmöglichkeiten zeigt sich, dass `bereitstellen` in der Bedeutung signifikant abweicht.

Bei den Bedeutungen nach DWDS zeigt sich, dass `sicherstellen` die größte Bedeutungsvielfalt hat. Während `bereitstellen` darauf fokussiert, etwas an einem bestimmten zur Verfügung zu stellen, fokussiert `gewährleisten` darauf, dass jemand die Garantie übernimmt, dass etwas so ist/ da ist - und nicht, es auch zu tun.

Im alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch kann jemand etwas `bereitstellen` und dennoch lediglich organisieren, dass jemand anderes das tut. Üblicher ist, dass der/diejenige es auch selbst macht.

`Gewährleisten` geht immer mit einem gewissen Garantieanspruch einher, und sei es nur als Indikator, dass es schwierig sein könnte, es zu tun. Die Wortähnlichkeit ist auch zu den juristischen Begriffen "Garantie" & "Gewährleistung" gegeben. Im juristischen Sinn ist "Garantie" die strengere Zusicherung (&Haftung) das etwas ist wie versprochen.

`Sicherstellen` ist m.E. die mündliche Variante von "gewährleisten". D.h., `ich stelle sicher, dass` ist wesentlich gebräuchlicher als `ich gewährleiste, dass` - und meint in diesem Fall dasselbe. Darüber hinaus kann ich auch `Beweise sicherstellen` - ich verhindere, dass eine Veränderung passiert und schütze etwas.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: ich verstehe nicht, was daran off-topic ist? Ich verstehe, dass "bereitstellen" quasi ausschert, doch "sicherstellen" und "gewährleisten" sind verdammt ähnlich. Bitte um Erhellung meines kleinen Begriffsverständnisses. Danke.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Für Sie liegt der Unterschied auf der Hand, aber Sie haben offenbar weder darüber nachgedacht noch nachgeforscht, warum diese Begriffe für irgendjemanden verwirrend sein könnten. Liefern Sie bitte ein Argument, warum es für Sie vermeintlich Off-Topic ist – mittlerweile finde ich Ihren Kommentar nicht zum Thema.